# Python warnings with cytypes Structure based class

Tags: python-3.x

The following code generates pep8 warnings in some places and not in others.  Can anyone explain the proper way to the following...

```
import ctypes


class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("_name", ctypes.c_char * 4)]

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        # validation code would be here
        self._name = value  # Generates warning: Instance attribute _name defined outside __init__

f = Test(_name=b"foo")
print(f.name)
f.name = b'bar'
print(f.name)
f._name = b'baz'  # No warning here??
print(f.name)


class Other:
    _foo = 1

x = Other()
print(x._foo)  # Generates warning: Access to a protected member _foo of a class
```

The Structure class provides the _name member, and will even initialize it via the constructor, but I've got no idea why the property setter is generating a warning.

I know why access to x._foo generates a warning, but not why f._name does not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!